# UITextView staying at nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to set up a UITextView so that it displays a message on a certain screen. Here's the relevant code:

```
//In the header file

IBOutlet UITextView* playerText;

-(void)playerThatWon:(int)player;

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView* playerText;


//In the main file

@synthesize playerText;

- (void)playerThatWon:(int)player
{
    if (player == 0) {[playerText setText:@""];}
    else if (player == 1) {[playerText setText:@"You win, Player 1!"];}
    else {[playerText setText:@"You win, Player 2!"];}
    BOOL text = [playerText hasText];
}
```

playerThatWon gets called from a different class after this class gets initialized. The "text" boolean was something that I set up to see if the UITextView had any text, and it returns NO when I check it in the debugger. Also, when I look at playerText in the debugger, it has no values or anything, like it wasn't even initialized. There are no problems in the IB, I hooked it up right, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How are you instantiating this view controller and calling the method?

Comment: `EndView = [[EndScreenViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`
`[EndView playerThatWon:1];`
`[self presentModalViewController:EndView animated:YES];`

Comment: Oh, and EndView is properly initialized in the header file

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@", playerText);` in the `playerThatWon:` method and tell us what you get.

Comment: `[Session started at 2011-06-16 18:59:01 -0700.]
2011-06-16 18:59:16.331 FunctionMachine[2148:207] (null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the connections are not loaded i.e. the NIB is not loaded yet. You should probably declare a property that you can set and later in `viewDidLoad` set the property to the text field.

<strike>Based on the log output, it looks like your outlets aren't connected properly. At least, `playerText` isn't connected properly as it is `nil`. You will have to recheck that connection.</strike>

Comment: Checked it. It's definitely connected to a UITextView that I set up in IB. It's also synthesized in the class, which I need to add in the post...

Comment: Ok. Add `NSLog("%@", self);` to the `playerThatWon:` method and add `NSLog(@"%@", EndView);` where you are initializing them and verify if they are the same.

Comment: Updated my answer. The NIB isn't loaded so `playerText` is `nil`. You will have to use a property or an instance variable as a middleman.

Comment: It worked! Just had to put it in the `viewDidLoad` method. Thanks for the help!